# what‘s difference between __attribute__((packed,aligned(n))) and __attribute__((aligned(n)))?

Tags: memory, gcc, memory-alignment

Is there any difference between **attribute**((packed,aligned(n))) and 
**attribute**((aligned(n))) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aligned` attribute specifies the *minimum* alignment the variable/field must have. The `packed` attribute requests that the variable/field should have the smallest possible alignment. So just using `__attribute__((aligned(n))` sets the minimum alignment to `n`, but does not guarantee that it won't be larger. But using `__attribute__((packed,aligned(n)))` sets the alignment to precisely `n`.